# Automatizando em Selenium com C# uma página Angular 6 que não possui elemento fixo

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde, estou tentando criar alguns testes automatizados numa página que não possui IDs fixos, a única forma segura está sendo XPath porém os mesmos vão mudar assim que um botão novo entrar.
Atualmente uma das linhas de código que eu utilizo é `WaitVisible(By.CssSelector("#mat-tab-label-0-1 > div));` porém frequentemente este 0-1 muda para 1-1, 2-1, e o teste quebra.

`<div cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple ng-star-inserted" mat-ripple="" mattablabelwrapper="" role="tab" ng-reflect-disabled="false" id="mat-tab-label-2-1" tabindex="-1" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="2" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-2-1" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false"><div class="mat-tab-label-content"><!--bindings={}--><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->Ranking</div></div>`
Este é o elemento que eu preciso que o selenium olhe, como da pra ver, o ID ja está mat-tab-label-2-1, portanto não é confiável, há alguma forma de pegar um elemento fixo no Angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendo de Angular, mas você pode tentar capturar o elemento através de outras formas que não o ID.

Como capturar todos os elementos que contenham essa classe, e selecionar apenas o primeiro, o último, ou como desejar.

Você também pode adicionar um atributo customizado neste elemento, e capturar os elementos que contenham este atributo.

Ou ainda capturar todos os elementos filhos de uma div, e capturar na ordem em que desejar, de acordo com a estrutura da página HTML.